# Windows Server 2008 command works in CMD but not in batch file

Tags: windows, csv, xp-cmdshell

I'm trying export csv (and other files) from numerous subfolders. These are archive folders that are being dropping dropped on our database server to be loaded. In any case I found two lines of code that work (or did work) but when loaded into a bat file or called by xp_cmdshell commands do not work.

These commands are intended to extract all the files located in multiple (hundreds) of sub directories. Again these work when I put them in the command prompt manually but not when called via bat(or cmd file) or xp_cmdshell from SQL-Server.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "C:\SPSData\UTDB1_Stage1"') do @move "%a" "C:\SPSData\UTDB1_Stage1"

MOVE C:\SPSData\UTDB1_Stage1\ *\ * C:\SPSData\UTDB1_Stage1\
```

Comment: "*dropping dropped*"? "*works in CMD but not in [...] CMD*"? You may want to reconsider that title.

Comment: Strictly it is not an MS-DOS command -  it is a *Windows shell command*; it does not rely on the MS-DOS subsystem or `command.com` to run, and in Win64 there is no MS-DOS sub-system in any case.  `cmd.exe` is a true  Windows executable and is not related to MS-DOS except in the sense that it shares a number of commands and command syntax.

Answer (score 2):

When used in a batch file, you need to escape the `%` variable introducer by prefixing with another `%` - substitute `%a` with `%%a`:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "C:\SPSData\UTDB1_Stage1"') do @move "%%a" "C:\SPSData\UTDB1_Stage1"
```

I would imagine that invocation via `xp_cmdshell` requires the same.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm embarrassed to admit how many hours I spent on this. Truly you made my day/ week.

Comment: @Ryan : You are welcome - it is pretty arcane knowledge familiar only perhaps to those who cut their teeth on MS-DOS.